Older App Launcher Icon is showing on FireTV Stick for live app
My app is showing older App Launcher Icon on Home screen for FireTV Stick.
I have updated the new assets for the live app for FireTV and published again, but even after successful app submission App Launcher Icon (app logo) on home screen grid has not been updated.
It is showing older App Launcher icon on FireTV Stick (Fire OS 7.6.7.9).

Could you please run the project in Android TV with Emulator and Check is it's change the icon in there? if Yes! Contact Amazon Support they will surely sort out this issue
